# What will be the Regex for word ending with alphabet lowercase or uppercase both?

Tags: jquery, regex

What will be the regex for a word ending with alphabet?

e.g.

> xyz,121%^&%^asasa
>   1212asas
>   ^%^asffa

should be allowed. But words like

> asa1212
>   @#fdf1212
>   121sdsd123

shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
\S*[a-zA-Z](?=\s|$)
```

`\S` would match any character which is **not** space..It's similar to `[^\s]`

`*` is a quantifier which matches preceding character **0 to many** times

`[a-zA-Z]` would match a single lowercase or uppercase alphabet

`(?=\s|$)` is a zero width lookahead which would match only if the pattern is followed by a space or is at the end(`$`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this regex is enough

> A string ending with alphabet(Uppercase or lowercase) matches the
>   regex

```
/[A-Za-z]$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The word should end in a letter?  If that is all you want then this should work...

```
\S*[a-zA-Z]+
```

Anything that's not whitespace followed by at least one letter.